# Sending asynchronous data to controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

How can I post the data from Ajax to the controller to get back inputted data? I have it already working with static information but would like a post back information from a table.

**Script**

```
    function postdata(data) {
    $.post("{{ URL::to('book/postdate') }}", { input:data }, function(returned){
        $('.book').html(returned);
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
{{ Form::text('date','', array('class' => 'datepicker', 'onChange' => 'postdata(this.value);')) }}

<div class="book"></div>
```

**Routes**

```
Route::post('book/postdate', 'BookController@postDate');
```

**Controller**

```
public function postDate() {

    echo 'hello';
}
```

Echoing `Hello` works fine but I want to send data to the controller with a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function postDate() {
     $date = Input::get('input');
     //Do whatever process you want.
     return "You post date: ".$date;
}
```

You can see the result in your console if you want

`console.log(returned);`

Comment: Cool, that did it I was using Input::get('data') previously. Thanks!